# What determines which weapons the team AI bots will use?

Tags: payday-2

[In this level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLqtV.jpg), I've noticed that the two team AI bots appear to be using the primary ([AK.762](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/AK.762)) and secondary weapon ([Compact-5](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Compact-5_%28Payday_2%29)) that I am currently using.

Does the weapon I'm currently using determine what the team AI bots will be using? Or is this decided by another factor? Do team AI bots also switch between their primary and secondary weapons, or do they use one weapon type only?

Do team AI bots use weapon mods? If yes, what determines which weapon mods the team AI bots will use? Is it the same as the host's currently equipped or stocked weapon mods?

Comment: I don't think it's determined just by what you have equipped; I've never seen an AI teammate use a shotgun, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the AI will carry the same weapon based on the character, not what the host has equipped; Dallas and Hoxton appear to be carrying an AK-47 with a folding stock, Wolf seems to carry a Compact-5 with an adjustable stock and the "Polizei tactical" foregrip, and Chains appears to carry a CAR-4 with holographic sight. They will always carry and use these weapons with these mods, regardless of what the host has equipped.

I determined which weapon each person had based on the viewmodel I saw and the rate of fire (to identify the rifle Hoxton and Dallas use as an AK-47).

The fact that they seemed to carry the same weapons as you was simply a coincidence.